# Mariadb 10.1, mysqld.sock file missing everytime sytem is restarted

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

I need Mariadb 10.1 for my requirements. 
Everytime i restart the system i get the following Error.

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

I tried a couple of solution found in the Internet but none seem to be working

- Tried Manually creating the sock file with owner as mysql.
- Tried restarting/starting the mysql server, gives error.

On running service mysql status

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.1.30 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2018-01-17 11:09:45 IST; 3min 43s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 1143 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 982 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemc
  Process: 974 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 967 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1143 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 17 11:09:42 infibeam-vostro-006 mysqld[1143]: 2018-01-17 11:09:42 140110739585792 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
Jan 17 11:09:42 infibeam-vostro-006 mysqld[1143]: 2018-01-17 11:09:42 140110739585792 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
Jan 17 11:09:43 infibeam-vostro-006 mysqld[1143]: 2018-01-17 11:09:43 140109819123456 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
Jan 17 11:09:43 infibeam-vostro-006 mysqld[1143]: 2018-01-17 11:09:43 140110739585792 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Jan 17 11:09:43 infibeam-vostro-006 mysqld[1143]: 2018-01-17 11:09:43 140110739585792 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushin
Jan 17 11:09:45 infibeam-vostro-006 mysqld[1143]: 2018-01-17 11:09:45 140110739585792 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 82
Jan 17 11:09:45 infibeam-vostro-006 mysqld[1143]: 2018-01-17 11:09:45 140110739585792 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Jan 17 11:09:45 infibeam-vostro-006 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.30 database server.
Jan 17 11:09:45 infibeam-vostro-006 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 17 11:09:45 infibeam-vostro-006 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'
```

Only solution that seems to be working is purging mysql from the system and re installing it.This is how i do it.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "mysql*"
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y mariadb-server
sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
sudo systemctl enable mariadb.service
```

But the next time i start the system, it gives the same error of sock file missing. Is there a solution for this. Is there a specific reason the file goes missing?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have enabled MySQL as a service (which would appear to be the case), then I suggest you do a `service mysql status` to see if the service has come up cleanly (if it hasn't it will show you some error messages).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you look at the error message i've added on the original post, on running mysql status.